# Visual Basic Excel Function to Name File off of Cell Content

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function in Visual Basic to create the filename of a spreadsheet based off of values in certain cells.

So far I have been using this code:

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()
ThisFile = "RWO_" + Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") + "_" + Format(Now(), "hhmm") + "_" + Range("D4").Value + "_" + Range("F5").Value + "_" + Range("D8").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile
End Sub
```

This code works the first time I save the file, however, whenever I resave the file, it does not update the file names based on new values in the cells.

Does anyone know how I could go about writing a function to do this?

Comment: do you have any error message? does it change time&date parts of the name or it doesn't change nothing within the name?

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors. It doesn't change anything in the name after it is modified, including the date and time.

Comment: change time part of the name into this: `Format(Now(), "hhmmss")` to see it's working while testing in immediate window in this way: `? "RWO_" + Format(Now(), "yyyymmddss") + "_" + Format(Now(), "hhmm") + "_" + Range("D4").Value + "_" + Range("F5").Value + "_" + Range("D8").Value`... is it or not?

Comment: I am not familiar with using the immediate window. However, I did add the 'ss' to the end of the time format. Now I notice that every time I run the code, the .xlsm file name on the title bar of the visual basic window updates with the new seconds. It looks like the file name might be updating. However, whenever I click save as, the file name in the save as window dialog box remains the old file name.

Comment: do you want this code to run each time you press `save as button` in Excel app? which Office version you are running?

Comment: Yes I would like the file name to be updated when the save as button is pressed. I am using Excel 2007. Sorry I did not mention this sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to do it by adding code for `BeforeSave event`. It will save file normally but will change the name as you expect each time you press `SaveAs button`.

This code should be located in `ThisWorkbook` module (Workbook module).

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    If SaveAsUI = True Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim ThisFile As String

        ThisFile = "RWO_" + Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") + "_" + Format(Now(), "hhmmss") + "_" + Range("D4").Value + "_" + Range("F5").Value + "_" + Range("D8").Value & ".xlsm"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile, FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Please note that I've change `ThisFile` by adding `ss` to time and `.xlsm` extension at the end. Also I've added `FileFormat parameter` to `.SaveAs method`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Good job of figuring it out and implementing, +1